# Can't create desired json data and read their values correctly (php, ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I'm making a clothes store and I want to display data in modal when product link is clicked. Each product can have more sizes and each size have its quantity.

This line opens modal (this work fine)

```
<a href="#" class="quick-view-btn" id="<?php echo $a_id; ?>"><span>View</span> </a>
```

The code below sends "id" to fetch_id.php file and displays data in modal

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.quick-view-btn').bind('click', function() {

        var id=$(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({
              url:"fetch_id.php",
              cache:false,
              data:'id='+id,
dataType: "json",


                          success:function(data){
        var aslika = data['artikli']['artslika'];              //get picture
        var aime = data['artikli']['artime'];          //get name
        var acijena = data['artikli']['artcijena'];           //get price
        var artcode = data['artikli']['artcode'];           //get art code
        var aopis = data['artikli']['artopis']; 


        
        $('.a_slika').attr("src", 'slike/'+aslika);
        $('.a_ime').html(aime);
        $('.a_cijena').html(acijena+' Kn');
        $('.a_artcode').html('šifra: '+artcode);
        $('.a_opis').html(aopis);
        $('.a_id').attr("href", 'single-product.php?id='+artcode);
        

               }
        }); 
    });
 });
  </script>
```

Here is my fetch_id.php file

```html
      $prid = $_GET['id'];
$active = 1;


 if ($stmtart = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT aid, art_code, glkat, kat, ime_a, opis, kolicina, cijena, stara_cijena, ocjena, slika, status, datum, xs, s, m, l, xl, xxl, xxxl FROM artikli WHERE status = ? and aid = ? LIMIT 1")) {
    
        $stmtart->bind_param('ii', $active, $prid );  
        $stmtart->execute();    
        $stmtart->store_result();
        $stmtart->bind_result($a_id, $aart_code, $a_glkat, $a_kat, $a_ime, $a_opis, $a_kolicina, $a_cijena, $a_scijena, $a_ocjena, $a_slika, $a_status, $a_datum, $a_xs, $a_s, $a_m, $a_l, $a_xl, $a_xxl, $a_xxxl);
        $stmtart->fetch();
  } 
  
  
   if ($stmtvelicine = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT vid, oznaka, kolicina FROM velicine WHERE artid = ? ORDER BY vid ASC")) {
    
        $stmtvelicine->bind_param('i', $prid );  
        $stmtvelicine->execute();    
        $stmtvelicine->store_result();
        $stmtvelicine->bind_result($v_id, $v_oznaka, $v_kolicina);

  }
  
   $artikli = array("artikli" => array("artslika"=>$a_slika, "artime"=>$a_ime, "artcijena"=>$a_cijena, "artcode"=>$aart_code, "artopis"=>$a_opis));
  
 $counter = 0;
  
   while($stmtvelicine->fetch()) {
   $counter = $counter + 1;
  
  $velicine = array('vel'.$counter => $v_oznaka);
  $komada = array('kom'.$counter => $v_kolicina);


  array_push($artikli, $velicine);
  array_push($artikli, $komada);
  }
  
  $json = json_encode($artikli);
   echo $json;
```

The result I'm receiving is in this format...

```
   {"artikli":{"artslika":"sn.jpg","artime":"Dress","artcijena":"129.56","artcode":"PD1001","artopis":"Default Description"},"0":{"vel1":"XS"},"1":{"kom1":5},"2":{"vel2":"L"},"3":{"kom2":2},"4":{"vel3":"XL"},"5":{"kom3":4}}
```

The problem is that my "while loop" creates numbers as keys so if some product have many sizes it will have many unknown keys.
Can you help me to read their values with ajax? Is there a better way to solve this?
Thank you very much,
Ivan.